# Связка сайта WP + WpEngine + Git

Tags: wordpress, git, github, hosting

Всем првиет!

Подскажите какие связки возможно использовать для контроля версий сайта на WP на хостинге WpEngine?

1. Есть ли смысл использовать утилиту local?
2. Если local единственный вариант, то безопасно ли будет работать с мультисайтами?
3. Какие наиболее распространённые варианты связок WpEngine + Git?

Comment: а почему именно такая концентрация под wpengine ? там есть ssh - поэтому все что нужно настроить можно. моя связка на хостинге для разворачивания на сервере - git, deployer, composer, wp-cli. на github нужно добавить в проект github-action и он все сделает на сервере

Comment: @Valerii Vasiliev очень интересно спасибо. А скажите, у вас мультисайт стоит? И ещё, если не трудно можете рассказать про этапы проведения работ на сайте.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-qqypD7FLs

Comment: @ValeriiVasiliev Благодарю!

Comment: 1. Если речь об этом: https://localwp.com/, то да, конечно. Разработка должна вестись локально. 2. С мультисайтами на локалке проблем нет. 3. Валерий дал хорошие комментарии, добавлю, что самый простой способ (если работаете один) - автоматически выгружать файлы коммита на сервер (WPEngine) из PhpStorm после коммита.

Comment: @KAGGDesign правильно ли я понял из вашего комментария, что утилиту local использовать можно и даже нужно? И чисто для запуска сайтов на локалке и версировать уже через связку которую описал Валерий?

Comment: Да, все приличные продуктовые компании работают именно так - разработка на локалке, фича в ветке, потом Pull Request в репозиторий. Тимлид и/или тестеры заливают на прод. Версионирование с помощью deployer - вещь полезная.

Comment: xdebug, тесты - всё на локалке. Ну и при коммите/PR в репу - тоже автоматические тесты.